# Python-Multiple conditions under if statement

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I am trying to write a function that will classify goods in a given dataset (in a very straightforward way, i know).

It looks like:

```py
def classifier(x):
    if ('smth' or 'smth' or 'smth') in x:
        return 'class1'
    elif ('smth' or 'smth' or 'smth') in x:
        return 'class2'
```

So, the problem is that some conditions do not work. When I try to check conditions separately - everything works. But in the function something goes wrong.

I use thing function with a pandas `apply`-method:

```py
data['classes'] = data['subj'].apply(lambda x: classifier(x))
```

Comment: `When I try to check conditions separately - everything works. But in the function something goes wrong.` can you elaborate?

Comment: @TZHX of course, but it will be in Russian... is it okay for you?

Comment: both `if` and `elif` conditions are same.

Comment: @nutcracker nyet, sadly.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani it is an example, just to show the structure

Comment: does [this question/answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) help you?

Comment: @nutcracker используй более реалистичные примеры, чем дубликаты в виде `'smth' or 'smth' or 'smth'`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest ну, к примеру, у меня есть позиция 'Сейф №(что-то там)' и внутри условия if если у меня `if 'Сейф' in x:`, то условие не срабатывает, а если проверять отдельно, то сработает

Comment: @nutcracker, пайтон так не работает, `('smth' or 'smth' or 'smth')` будет вычислять/сравнивать сами значения по логическому приведению, а не вхождения в список `x`

Comment: @nutcracker, welcome, лови лайк )

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest and OP, questions and answers, as well as their respective comments, are supposed to be useable for everyone here. So yould anybody check if there is valuable information and translate it to English?

Comment: @glglgl, the 1st paragraph in my answer reflects the matter (and elaboration) of those comments. (I've added it after those short comments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`('smth' or 'smth' or 'smth')` performs a consecutive logical comparison left-to-right, but not check for occurrence each of them within a target sequence.

To check if any value from a predefined list (iterable) occurs within a *target* sequence `x` use builtin `any` function:

```
def classifier(x):
    if any(i in x for i in ('a', 'b', 'c')):
        return 'class1'
    elif any(i in x for i in ('d', 'e', 'f')):
        return 'class2'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```py
def classifier(x):
    if 'smth' in x or 'smth' in x or 'smth' in x:
        return 'class1'
    elif 'smth' in x or 'smth' in x or 'smth' in x:
        return 'class2'
```

You have to check for each condition separately.

Comment: is there any difference?

Comment: You have to ask all conditions separately.

Comment: why? https://python-forum.io/Thread-Simplifying-multiple-or-conditions-in-if-statement

Comment: @nutcracker that link says it doesnt work (the example that does is a fluke and should not be relied on). `('a' or 'b')` is evaulated to produce a string (or possibly boolean) first, which is then used in the membership test. You likely want to know if either is in `x`, so you need to ask if either is `in x`.